# I have almost no idea how to factor numbers this big.

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

$14425638854646469646839767613420413647898432138735230192512819$ is the product of two prime numbers. Each factor is an answer.

I have to give both factors as answers. How would I get to them and which numbers are them?

My knowledge of factors is extremely limited.

Comment: This is a difficult question and it is due to the difficulty of the problem that current RSA cryptosystems are secure.

Comment: This is the product of two very nearly equal (31 digit) primes.  So a quadratic sieve approach made quick work of it.  I'm not sure what your interest in the problem is ("I have to give both factors as answers") nor whether your background enables you to follow the suggestion I'm making about how to proceed.

Comment: @JMoravitz got this question asked as part of a puzzle (itstoohard.com/puzzle/162jpyKr question 3). If you don't mind explaining, how are these numbers related to RSA encryption? Total noob on the field but the theme sounds interesting.

Comment: @hardmath my previous knowledge is definitely lacking. You can see my other comment for more background. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @hardmath can you explain the quadratic sieve approach? Do you basically start near the square root and try primes?

Comment: @BenjaminWang:  That approach is called [Fermat's factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method).  [Quadratic sieve methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) are a modern development of the ideas, introduced in 1981 by [Carl Pomerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Pomerance).

Comment: With regards to the relation to RSA and other cryptosystems, see [Rabin cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem), [RSA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem), and [RSA Factoring Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge).  Also, of particular historical interest to mathematical lore surrounding this, [The Magic Words are Squeamish Ossifrage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Words_are_Squeamish_Ossifrage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $3658265762777653112540162274181 \cdot 3943299855747317419837769926999$ :)

edit:
To find the factorization, I used the function [`ifactor`](https://maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=ifactor) in Maple, which itself relies on the quadratic sieve method, as explained in its [documentation](https://maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=ifactor).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sergey. 

If you allow me, did you use a quadratic sieve approach as previously mentioned by @hardmath? Would that be the simplest way to solve this?

And at which "general level" of mathematical study should I learn how to solve the problem/have the background required, if you would happen to know? I am not yet in uni.

Comment: You are welcome. I just used the function `ifactor` in Maple, which itself indeed relies on the quadratic sieve. You can look up the references in https://maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=ifactor, but they are quite involved.